# Разница между размещением API модулей в монолитном приложении

Tags: архитектура

Есть монолит с несколькими модулями, нужно выбрать куда помещать интерфейсы API и data structure.
Есть два варианта
Допустим есть два модуля module1 и module2

1. Разместить API package of module1 с интерфейсами, в module1 и как бы его выставлять наружу для использованиями другими модулями а реализация будет в module1/server.
2. Разместить API package of module1 с интефейсами, в модуле module2 который будет использовать эти интерфейсы, а реализация будет в module1/serer.

Какие есть плюсы и минусы и что лучше использовать?

Comment: Вы нарисуйте схему как это всё у вас будет выглядеть в разных вариантах, тогда вам же понятнее будет. И что за " другие модули", сколько их, как они обращаются к этим модулям и между собой, почему вопрос только об архитектуре тех двух модулей, а не системы в целом? Нарисуйте прям всё-всё что у вас есть и как оно взаимодействует в двух вариантах, тогда можно думать дальше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вынести в третий модуль общие интерфейсы и использовать их из обоих. Тогда зависимости между двумя модулями не будут иметь значения.

Answer (score 0):

Извините, но я начну по другому и ничего нового у меня нет.

В не зависимости от архитектуры так или иначе от [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) мы далеко не уходим. Для этого вопроса нам интересны 2 последние буквы.

**I** - **Принцип разделения интерфейса** *(The Interface Segregation Principle)*

> из него следует не создавайте больших интерфейсов (это не запрет,а
> принцип). Разделение интерфейса облегчает использование и тестирование
> модулей.

**D** - **Принцип инверсии зависимостей** *(The Dependency Inversion Principle)*

> Модули верхних уровней не должны зависеть от модулей нижних уровней.
> Оба типа модулей должны зависеть от абстракций. Абстракции не должны
> зависеть от деталей. Детали должны зависеть от абстракций.

Так из этих двух принципов.

1. Вынести интерфейсы/абстракции выше уровня модулей их использующие.
2. Если модули на одном уровне, то о никакой зависимости речи быть не может.
   Модули хранят реализации интерфейсов (классы они же детали) и зависят от абстракции (abstract class, interface). Также модули хранят абстракции (abstract class, interface) для нижних уровней.

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать доводы в сторону минуса, если не затруднит.